# ACF location rule, show everywhere

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the ACF (advanced custom fields) plugin in WordPress. I have a group and I want it to show at every page/post/custom post type/etc.

At rules, I can say that a group will only be shown at, for example, a certain page. But can I say that I want it to show everywhere?

Comment: maybe post also some code..

Comment: Code? What should I post?

Comment: well SO is about programming.. you are altering some plugin.. so post what you have tried so far ;)

Comment: I haven't programmed anything, it's about setting the location rules for ACF in the WordPress backend

Comment: well then I am not sure if this is good site for such question.. maybe is .. but when I checked few [wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) questions they are always talking about code..

Comment: I am just looking for someone who understands the ACF plugin slightly better than me, and from my experience with SO, this seems to be a good place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem seemed to be, that the whole piece of code was inside an function, and the function was made into a shortcode. When I tried to get, for example, the title of a custom post (in this case the post type 'case'), it simply would not communicate with this post type, for some reason.

I took the piece of code out of the function, and called it directly, which seemed to work.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want the group fields to be shown at all the editors, or do you want the fields filled in at a certain page to be shown at other pages also?

**Adding a group to multiple page/posts types**

This is easy, you can apply more than one rule to a group.

so:

If type is same as post +

if type is same as page +

and so on...

**Use a certain field's input from one page on other pages**

If you have filled in some custom fields on a certain page, and you want to use that same input on other pages, use the following line:

```
<?php the_field('field_name', original_post_or_page_id); ?>
```

**Creating a global group**

You can also use a global group to be shown on all pages. I use this extension: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/options-page/

Comment: <?php the_field('field_name', original_post_or_page_id); ?> Very useful thanks!